# mapping array of keys to array of values for substitution

Tags: jq

Given this data, which is two distinct objects, one having an array of keys and the other a dictionary of key value pairs:

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "location": "server4",
      "services": [
        "srv07",
        "srv06",
        "srv01",
        "srv04"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "server2",
      "services": [
        "srv07",
        "srv02",
        "srv05",
        "srv03"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "release": {
    "id": "release1",
    "services": [
      {
        "service": "srv01",
        "URL": "/srv01_service/v1.20.0"
      },
      {
        "service": "srv02",
        "URL": "/srv02_service/v1.14.0"
      },
      {
        "service": "srv03",
        "URL": "/srv03_service/v1.15.0"
      },
      {
        "service": "srv04",
        "URL": "/srv04_service/v1.18.0"
      },
      {
        "service": "srv05",
        "URL": "/srv05_service/v1.14.0"
      },
      {
        "service": "srv06",
        "URL": "/srv06_serv/v1.13.0"
      },
      {
        "service": "srv07",
        "URL": "/srv07_service/v1.19.0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to produce this, the first object with the keys replaced with the values from the dictionary.  NOTE:  I would be fine with renaming services[] to URLs[] if it makes things easier.

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "location": "server4",
      "services": [
        "/srv07_service/v1.19.0",
        "/srv06_serv/v1.13.0",
        "/srv01_service/v1.20.0",
        "/srv04_service/v1.18.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "server2",
      "services": [
        "/srv07_service/v1.19.0",
        "/srv02_service/v1.14.0",
        "/srv05_service/v1.14.0",
        "/srv03_service/v1.15.0"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My latest attempt is close but returns something akin to a Cartesian.

```
. |  .servers[].services[] = (.servers[] as $s | .release.services[] | select(.service as $v | $s.services[] | index($v)).URL) | {servers}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `INDEX` to lookup in, then `map` each element you want to change according to the index.

```sh
jq '
  INDEX(.release.services[]; .service) as $index
  | {servers} | .servers[].services[] |= $index[.].URL
'
```

```json
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "location": "server4",
      "services": [
        "/srv07_service/v1.19.0",
        "/srv06_serv/v1.13.0",
        "/srv01_service/v1.20.0",
        "/srv04_service/v1.18.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "server2",
      "services": [
        "/srv07_service/v1.19.0",
        "/srv02_service/v1.14.0",
        "/srv05_service/v1.14.0",
        "/srv03_service/v1.15.0"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/clxujSEL6e)

Comment: AHA!  I was indexing at the end of my filtering, not at the start.  Brilliant.  Many thanks!

Comment: Also note that you have used `index` while I am using `INDEX`, which are different functions.

Comment: I noticed that.  All of this makes sense to me except the `[.]` near the end.  Could you paraphrase what that is all about?

Comment: `|=` is the update operator. It assigns to the LHS the value on the RHS (as does `=`) but in doing so, it also presets the context (which is `.`) on the RHS to match that on the LHS. So, in this case, `.` takes the value of the iteration step in `services[]` and uses it as key for the lookup in `$index`.

Comment: This solution has worked well but the input data has changed since posting.  Now `servers` with no `services` present can occur.  This causes "Cannot iterate over null" issues.  I tried using `// empty` to no avail.    
  
p.s. perfectly willing to post as a separate question if preferred.  
p.s.s. don't have the rep to upvote but will once I get there

Comment: @JimHastings Simply add a `?` to the LHS of the update assignment: `.servers[].services[]? |= $index[.].URL`. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xiUE2cxOON4) This [Error Suppression / Optional Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ErrorSuppression%2FOptionalOperator%3A%3F) cancels the update if the LHS produces an error. Alternatively you can use a [try-catch](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#try-catch) clause by putting `try` before it: `try .servers[].services[] |= $index[.].URL` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7EFR0h-9xOY)